# meaning of "found" in "found workers scrambling to find jobs"

Tags: word-meaning

In the following sentence, what does "found" mean? Can its definition be found in any dictionaries?

> News of the factory closing **found** workers scrambling to find jobs.

https://www.britannica.com/dictionary/scramble

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Factory workers were scrambling to find jobs at the time the factory closure was announced.

An event can find people doing something or in a state or condition. I could not sleep and daylight found me staring out of the window. I spent the train journey reading about algebra, and my arrival at Oxford found me ready to answer the professor's questions. The sudden enemy attack found the soldiers unprepared, and many were killed or taken prisoner.

> 6. VERB [no passive, no cont]
>
> If a time or event finds you in a particular situation, you are in
> that situation at the time mentioned or when the event occurs.
>
> *Daybreak found us on a cold, clammy ship.*
>
> *His lunch did not take long to arrive and found him poring over his*
> *notepad*.

[Find (Collins Dictionary)](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/find)

Comment: Thank you. Does "see" have the same usage in that sort of context?

Comment: @Apollyon - yes, 'see' would work too.

Comment: Does the OP example imply a causal relation between the arrival of the news and the workers' scrambling for new jobs?

Comment: @Apollyon - No causal relationship, just simultaneity. They were scrambling for jobs **at the time** the closure was announced. I expect they knew the company was in trouble and had been told some time beforehand.

Comment: @Apollyon - I once worked for a company that was in trouble. The workers were told one month before that the factory would close and that we would need to look for new jobs. Sometimes, however, no prior warning is given. In that case, there would be a causal relationship.